# CRM 2011: Wsdl web service doesn't contain my entities

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

We will soon upgrade to CRM 2011 so I'm doing some tests. The problem is that when I change my web service reference to the 2011 one, my application stops compiling. It just won't find any entity (example of line that stops working: `Account acc = new Account()` -> It says that I must miss a reference).

When I compare the web services of the CRM 4 to the one of the CRM 2011, I see that it's true. The CrmService of CRM 4 contains the definition of every entity of the CRM, but they do not appear in the CRM 2011!

Why is that? Am I missing something? Do I need to activate something?

Just to make sure, here are the URLs I'm using:

http://myserver/mscrmservices/2006/CrmServiceWsdl.aspx -> Works perfectly

http://myserver/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx?WSDL -> Does not contain entity definition

http://myserver/mscrmservices/2007/CrmService.asmx?WSDL&uniquename=MyOrg -> Does not contain entity definition

http://myserver/mscrmservices/2007/crmservicewsdl.aspx -> Does not contain entity definition

Comment: Did you use a Web Reference, or a Service Reference? Which version of Visual Studio and .NET are you using?

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 and I use a Web Reference

Comment: you should try Service Reference, which is what you should use in general.

Comment: You're right! But it doesn't correct my issue as my issue is directly in the aspx page.

Comment: have you tried with Service Reference? It's what generates the classes like `Account`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using the wrong endpoints.

Dynamics CRM 2011 introduces a complete new WCF based web service.

It's endpoint is `http://ServerName/OrganizationName/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc` See [the endpoint overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309401.aspx#OrganizationService)

So you should either add a Service Reference (See [Use the WSDL Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509052.aspx)) or use early/late bound access (See [Write Code for Microsoft Dynamics CRM (Web Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334357.aspx)

The endpoints you mention in your post are for legacy purposes. See the article [Use the Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 (2007) Endpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334316.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I recently came across a similiar situation. We are actually using CRM 4.0 (not 2011), and I was experiencing the same issues you are having. I came across this article:

http://www.stunnware.com/crm2/topic.aspx?id=HelpCustomizations

Basically, a reboot and refresh of the Web Service in VS fixed the issue. It looks like CRM doesn't constantly build these Web Services (which makes sense).