# Dynamics CRM 2011 webservice with Delphi?

Tags: web-services, delphi, dynamics-crm-2011

Has anyone used Delphi or another non-microsoft language to connect to the dynamics crm 2011 webservice?
The only examples I can find are with the SDK and the WDSL is no help. 
In previous versions of CRM the WDSL contained all entities and (custom) properties, now the WDSL is basicly empty.

Comment: In a similar situation with Dynamics CRM we chose to write a service proxy in C# which communicates with the CRM. Then we used a simple EDI file based interface to the Delphi side. Writing a HTTP based (RESTful) service on the C# side which can be consumed from Delphi using Indy or Synapse would have been the next higher level.

Answer (score 2):

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5275285/800214) points out that the Dynamics WS no longer exists and you have to use WCF now. I can tell you that Delphi does not fully support WCF so you will have to build a .NET wrapper DLL in C# or VB.

Comment: The problem is not that the WCF is not usable from Delphi, I can import the WDSL from the endpoint, but that it does not provide the information needed to call the entity's.

Comment: what endpoint are you using? Like I said don't even think of consuming WCF in delphi, it's a waste of time...